# CSS fixed-sized box above scaling box

Tags: css

Consider

```
<div id="foo">
  Lorem ipsum
</div>
<div id="bar">
  sit amet
</div>
```

Is it possible to keep the size of foo, and have bar to fill the rest of the page when window size changes, using only CSS. foo is a fixed sized top banner. What should the height property of bar be? Yes,

```
screen.height-padding-getElementById("foo").style.height
```

But I would prefer to do it without a script.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you're asking for, if not give me a comment and I can modify:

```
#foo {
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    background: red;
}
#bar {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 100%;
    background: blue;
}
```

DEMO: [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/BCVLn/)

Comment: The page becomes 50px to high

Comment: I chose 50px to demonstrate a "fixed sized top banner". You can change 50px to whatever you'd like, or remove it if you want the element height to be the size of the text.

Comment: I want bar to have the height 100%-50px (or whatever the size of that box is)

Comment: So trick with margin or padding and set top to 0. You need to modify your answer, then I will accept it.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at [CSS Media Queries](http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/)
You can then assign whatever properties to your elements during screen resize without using a script.

Example:

```
body{
  background-color: #fff; 
}

#foo{
  width: 200px;
}

@media all and (max-width: 699px) and (min-width: 520px), (min-width: 1151px) {
  body {
    background: #ccc;
  }
  #foo{
    width: 400px;
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't think this answers his question.

Comment: Couldnt he just use media queries to manipulate the size of attributes on screen re-size ? How else would he do it with pure css ?

Comment: Posted an answer based on my interpretation of the question. I could be wrong also, but I think OP means a top div that is a fixed height with a second div that fills the remaining space.